# Create a pandas column with values from filtering string values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe as:

```
Feature     Prediction 
Dell 12-4.  Grade 1
Dell 12-5.  Grade 1
Dell 10-4.  Grade 1
Dell 10-5.  Grade 0
Dell 12-6.  Grade 0
```

I would like to create a new column called 'True Outcome', which filters Feature Column for strings that starts with 'Dell 12-' and assigns Grade 0 to it otherwise Grade 1.

The expected output should look like this:

```
Feature     Prediction  True Outcome
Dell 12-4.  Grade 1.    Grade 0
Dell 12-5.  Grade 1.    Grade 0
Dell 10-4.  Grade 1.    Grade 1
Dell 10-5.  Grade 0.    Grade 1
Dell 12-6.  Grade 0.    Grade 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To find if the column starts with the requested string, you can use

```
df.Feature.str.startswith('Dell 12-')
```

and the assignment can be

```
import numpy as np
df['Outcome'] = np.where(df.Feature.str.startswith('Dell 12-'), 'Grade 0', 'Grade 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a column with all 1s - then set all the values where `feature` contains `Dell-12`

```py
df["True Outcome"] = 1  #Create column
df.loc[df["features"].str.startswith("Dell 12") ,"True Outcome"]=0 #Set the values to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach:

```
df['True Outcome'] = np.where(df['Feature'].str.startswith('Dell 12'), 'Grade 0', 'Grade 1')
```